# where query is not working properly in Grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy, where-clause

I am working on some project in Grails and using `where` query.

I figured out that it is returning more data than it should be.

I put in third row `false` value in order to make `where` return empty list.
However, list is not empty.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code.

Here are two examples(I tried both options and both return list which is not empty).

Example 1:

```
List<Settings> settingsList = Settings.where{
            userId == user.id &&
            startDateData.specificDate <= specificDate &&
            false
        }.list(sort:"startDateData", order:'desc')
```

Example 2:

```
List<Settings> settingsList = Settings.where{
            userId == user.id
            startDateData.specificDate <= specificDate
            false
        }.list(sort:"startDateData", order:'desc')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only expressions that directly affect the query criteria are those for which the LHS references a persistent property.  The expression `false` isn't one of those expressions.

Comment: What is LHS exactly?

Comment: LHS is "Left Hand Side"

Comment: In the expression `x > 5`, `x` is the LHS.